# AWS Cloudwatch Metric Math, Group Measuremnts and return Max for each group

Tags: math, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

I have a metric in AWS for my SQS "NumberOfMessagesReceived". I grab the Sample Count in a period of 1 min over a time frame of 3 hours. How can I group these measurements in groups of 5 min, so 5 measurements, and return the max value for each group. Essentially a Max Sample Count in a 5 min period. I can't just change the period here becuase it will just return cumulative (sum'd) values, which is what it's doing now, but for 1 min segments.

[image: metric]

Thanks.